# How to calculate running total for a SortedMap / TreeMap

Tags: scala, dictionary

So I have the following `SortedMap`:

```scala
val mySortedMap: SortedMap[Double, Int] = SortedMap(1.1 -> 7, 2.4 -> 3, 6.5 -> 12)
```

Now I need to calculate the running total for each key, so the output should look like this:

```scala
val result: SortedMap[Double, Int] = SortedMap(1.1 -> 7, 2.4 -> 10, 6.5 -> 22)
```

I know I can do something similar by using `scanLeft`:

```scala
val result: Iterable[Int] = mySortedMap.scanLeft(0)((c, e) => c + e._2)
```

But this returns `Iterable` whereas I need to keep my `SortedMap` as specified above. What is the most functional / efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft` where your *accumulator* is both, a new **SortedMap** and the running total.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

def runningTotal(map: SortedMap[Double, Int]): SortedMap[Double, Int] = {
  val (transformed, _) = map.foldLeft((SortedMap.empty[Double, Int], 0)) {
    (acc, element) =>
      val (mapAcc, totalAcc) = acc
      val (key, value) = element
      val newTotal = totalAcc + value
      val newMap = mapAcc + (key -> newTotal)
      (newMap, newTotal)
  }
  transformed
}
```

---

Bonus, here is your solution but using **Iterators** instead, thus it would be a little bit more efficient.

```
def runningTotal(map: SortedMap[Double, Int]): SortedMap[Double, Int] = {
  val newValues = map.valuesIterator.scanLeft(0) {
    (acc, value) => acc + value
  }.drop(1)

  map.keysIterator.zip(newValues).to(SortedMap)
}
```

Comment: `foldLeft` solution worked great, thanks! one minor thing is that `SortedMapOps.+` is deprecated since scala 2.13.0 so just had to replace the affected line with `val newMap = mapAcc ++ Map(key -> newTotal)`

Comment: @msilb `+` is not deprecated if you are using an **Immutable** `SortedMap`, that is why I added the import at the begging. I would suggest you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I might have found one possible solution:

```scala
val input: SortedMap[Double, Int] = SortedMap(1.1 -> 7, 2.4 -> 3, 6.5 -> 12)
val aggregates: Iterable[Int] = mySortedMap.scanLeft(0)((c, e) => c + e._2).tail
val sortedAggregates: SortedMap[Double, Int] = input.keySet.zip(aggregates).to(SortedMap)
println(sortedAggregates)
```

gives `TreeMap(1.1 -> 7, 2.4 -> 10, 6.5 -> 22)`.

I wonder if there is a better way?